# Build output window in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

I have a very embarrassing question about TeXnicCenter. I'm sure this is very stupid, but it is driving me crazy.

Normally, when you build a `.tex` file TeXnicCenter displays the build output (errors, warnings, etc.) in long horizontal window underneath the `.tex` file.

For example, this can be seen in the following image from the TeXnicCenter website:
http://www.texniccenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/gui.png
[image]

However, I somehow did something, and now my build output appears in a long **vertical** window on the left side of my screen, where the project outline appears in the image above.

I cannot for the life of me move it back. I have tried dragging and dropping, and/or unpinning the build output window, but these do not allow me to put it back below the `.tex`.  I have tried right-clicking the horizontal area below the `.tex` and clicking "build output" but that only replaces the build output window on the left side.

EDIT: To use the language Mensch used in his answer (which didn't work for me), I would like the build output window to be "docked" below the .tex, not to the left of it. Here is a photo of what my situation looks like

[image]

I'd like to return the build output window to be docked below the tex, as in the first image in my post.

I'm sure this is very silly, but can anyone give me a clue here?

Comment: Ah, Scott H's comment has fixed it for me. I have been dragging around this window all afternoon without success, but your specific instruction helped me. I admit that my old eyes did not find it easy to pick out the right moment. Thanks again. I don't think I can "accept" your comment, but if you write it as an answer I can. Sorry for the embarrassing query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag and drop it to where you want it.  Drag it to the very bottom of the **text entry** area.  Move it around a bit it can be hard to see when the outline snaps to that spot.  I just did it on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you clicked inside the title of that window and moved it out of TeXnicCenter, you allowed to let it float ...

The trick to get the window back inside TeXnicCenter is simple (okay--if you know it).

See the following situation:

[image: starting situation]

Window `Erstellung` (German language) is floating. To get it back into TeXnicCenter click right on the title line. Then you see the following window

[image: context menu in title line]

and click there on `docking`.  Then you get your wished layout back:

[image: old layout of TeXnicCenter]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this didn't work for me. I am able to make the build output window "float" (by double clicking). Then I followed your directions: right click, check "docking". This simply put the window back to be vertical on the left side, rather than underneath as in the image in my post.

Comment: To be clear, my build output window is "docked", just in the wrong place! I can switch it between "docked vertically" and "floating", but I cannot make it docked horizontally underneath.

Comment: Why do you not add an screenshot of your current screen to your question? And mark there the issue. Then we have not to guess what has happend on your system @anon

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to do so now. Apologies, I am new to stackexchange.